# How to prevent dependency mutating an object that is passed in as a parameter without recloning every time

Tags: javascript, typescript

Say I have a data object which is my 'state'. Take the example of colors, and how they relate to each other respectively.

```
const data = {
   colors: [
     {id: 1, name: "black", hex: "#000"},
     {id: 2, name: "white", hex: "#fff"},
     {id: 3, name: "grey", hex: "#bbb"}
   ],
   relations: [
     {id: 1, from: 3, to: 1},
     {id: 2, from: 3, to: 2},
   ]
}
```

This data object is maintained and update in my code with functions such as `removeColor`, `addColor`, `filterColors`, and I pass it to a dependency to be graphed.

**The problem is that the dependency mutates my own data object that I passed in.** It will add its own properties and change some of mine for its graphing purposes.

i.e. the item for black would be changed by the dependency to now be

```
{id: 12, name: 'black', hex: "#000", x: 500, y:500, z: 0.05, hidden: false},
```

Not only is it overriding my own id, but it adds on values to the object too.

***I could deep clone my object before passing it in to the dependency*** HOWEVER, every time I change some part of the object on my side, it *reclones* the data object, and creates a whole brand new clone which is a problem with it basically treating it as a whole new render... Once i clone the data object, separating it from my own state, I need the dependency to stay referencing that given object. I can't give it a brand new data object on every change.

---

What I am looking for is a way to clone the data object initially, so that it isn't mutated by the dependency. But also whenever I change an item in one of the arrays of my own data object, it changes it in the cloned dependency too WITHOUT creating a whole brand new clone - it simply makes that change on the initial cloned data object.

i.e. if I add `show: false` to my item `grey` then I need to do the same on the cloned data object, I need to access the `grey` item in the colors array and add `show: false`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to manage access to an object. On reading properties you could forward to the original data object. On writing properties you just do nothing.

While I think this answers your question, keep in mind that this could break your dependency. If the dependency sets a variable and afterwards it is not the expected value, maybe it fails (e.g. if it uses the id for internal purposes).

That said, here's an example of using a Proxy in your scenario:

```js
const data = {
   colors: [
     {id: 1, name: "black", hex: "#000"},
     {id: 2, name: "white", hex: "#fff"},
     {id: 3, name: "grey", hex: "#bbb"}
   ],
   relations: [
     {id: 1, from: 3, to: 1},
     {id: 2, from: 3, to: 2},
   ]
}

const createHandler = (obj) => {
  return {
    get(target, prop, receiver) {
      const val = obj[prop]
      // If the value is an object, we return another proxy
      // so the dependency also has no access to nested properties
      return typeof val === 'object' ? new Proxy(val, createHandler(val)) : val
    },
    set(target, prop, receiver) {
      // no-op
    }
  }
}

// proxy passed to dependency
proxy = new Proxy(data, createHandler(data))

console.log('initial value', proxy.relations[0].id)
proxy.relations[0].id = 10
console.log('after proxy writing', proxy.relations[0].id)
data.relations[0].id = 10
console.log('after original writing', proxy.relations[0].id)
```

Comment: would it be possible to simply restrict the dependency from overwriting the existing values? meaning it can add properties, just not change the ones that were existing in the original

Comment: yes, I think so. currently the `set(...)` method does nothing, so no property is set. If you want to allow adding new properties, you could check if the original obj contains the prop. If yes, do nothing. If no, set the property.

Comment: Also a side note: A dependency which has such unintended side effects sounds weird. I'd suggest you to consider modifying the dependency or exchange it for another one